# QUIC support for Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Is Google Cloud Platform able to use QUIC protocol or it is only limited to HTTP/2? If not, any Cloud Platform is supporting QUIC protocol today?

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible, you can see their [blog post](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/06/Introducing-QUIC-support-for-HTTPS-load-balancing.html) or [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#QUIC).